# Guake and gnome-terminal $PATH

Tags: gnome-terminal, guake

Most of the time I use Guake as terminal emulator.  Today I wanted to start a program from gnome-terminal and it tells me that it's not installed currently, although I ran the program a minute ago on Guake.

When I `echo $TERM`, I get `xterm` on both, however `echo $PATH` in gnome-terminal differs.  Does anyone know what this is about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that you modified the `$PATH` in Guake. If you're able to run the program from Guake, copy `$PATH` and then use the following command in gnome-terminal:

```
export PATH=<path copied from Guake>
```

Now try to run the program. If you want it to remain the same permanently, put the above line in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Yes, the `$PATH` in Guake was somehow modified, and now after restarting the computer I can not access the program from Guake either.  I guess I'll have to figure out which directories to include in $PATH in order to be able to use it.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So here is what the problem was. The program I was trying to run was `(ruby on) rails`. When installed, it adds a line in `.bash_login` file to export path. However, `.bash_login` is not executed by default by Guake or gnome-terminal, because they don't run commands as a `login-shell`. In order to set gnome-terminal to run commands as a `login-shell`, check the `Run command as a login shell` checkbox at `Edit/Profile Preferences/Title and Command`. Same goes for Guake. 

For more on login and non-login shell: http://www.admon.org/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/